# C++ Game of Life infinite looping function

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

This function in the Game of Life assignment is supposed to loop through the 2nd array and check to see how many neighbors each cell has. When I call this in the main, not even in any sort of loop, the terminal freezes as if in an infinite while loop. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks.

```
void Grids::simulate(int** myGrid, int rows, int columns)
{
    int neighbors = 0; //variable to store how many neighbors a cell has
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r) // iterates through rows
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < columns; ++c)//iterates through columns
        {
            for(int x = -1; x < 2; x + 2) //iterates through -1 and 1, the spaces next to the cell
            {
                for(int y = -1; y < 2; y + 2)
                {
                    if ((r + x >= 0) && (r + x < rows) && (c + y >= 0) && (c + y < columns)) //prevents indexing the 2d array outside of its bounds
                    {
                        if (myGrid[r + x][c + y] == 1) //checks if the surrounding cells are alive
                        {
                            ++neighbors;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (neighbors < 2) //underpopulation
            {
                myGrid[r][c] = 0; //dead
            }
            else if (neighbors == 3) //reproduction
            {
                myGrid[r][c] = 1; //alive
            }
            else if (neighbors >= 4) //overpopulation
            {
                myGrid[r][c] = 0; //dead
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On your third and fourth `for` loop, are `x+2` and `y+2` typos?

Comment: This seems to be a typo. `for(int x=-1; x<2; x+2)`. `x+2` does not change `x`. That's why you have an infinite loop.  Did you mean to use `for(int x=-1; x<2; x += 2)`? Same problem exists with `for(int y=-1;y<2;y+2)`.

Comment: This won't work anyway. You cannot update a grid in place this way, it doesn't follow the rules of the game.

Comment: Game of life requires you to start each new generation on a clean grid.  Then update the cells of the new grid referencing cells on the old grid.  As you have it, you're making decisions based on both updated cells and unvisited cells.  Not what you want.  This will not generate the board you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this `x + 2` to `x += 2` and `y + 2` to `y += 2`, to make the loop increase by 2 each cycle. I also advise you to remove extra parentheses in this line `if (r + x >= 0 && r + x < rows && c + y >= 0 && c + y < columns)`.